# AWS Cognito Custom domain: The limit for custom domains is: 4. LimitExceededException;

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We use AWS Cognito, with 2 user pools. Each user pool has one prefix domain, which work as expected.

Now I am trying to set up a custom domain for one user pool as per the instructions here: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-add-custom-domain.html

But the following error occurs:

*The limit for custom domains is: 4. (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: LimitExceededException;Request ID: xxx-xxx-xxx)*

I use the Management console, as root account owner, who has the permission to create custom domains and cloudfront distributions, i assume. I also use Route53 as the DNS provider and have a wildcard SSL certificate in AWS Certificate manager, for the domain name used.

I don't have even one custom domain. Why is it throwing a LimitExceededException?

Comment: Just for closure. This got resolved on its own and I could add custom domain. Not sure if this was some bug at AWS. Sorry, hopefully no one else faces this issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Just encounter the same problem here. looks like it's a known issue.

Answer (score -2):

Please check :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html
Maximum number of custom domains per account    is 4

Comment: Is fact and known, but the questions is why the limit ist exeeded when no custom domain is used in this account.